Error: Unable to initialize main class email.sendEmail Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException
//here is my code
package email;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.activation.*;
public class sendEmail {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     String to = "sanket85@gmail.com";//change accordingly  
      String from = "sanket23@gmail.com";//change accordingly  
      String host = "localhost";//or IP address  
  
     //Get the session object  
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();  
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);  

      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);  
  
     //compose the message  
      try{  
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));  
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));  
         message.setSubject("Ping");  
         message.setText("Hello, this is example of sending email  ");  
  
         // Send message  
         Transport.send(message);  
         System.out.println("message sent successfully....");  
  
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {mex.printStackTrace();}  
   }  

}

1.when I try to run program     Error: Unable to initialize main class email.sendEmail
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException`
this error occurs.
I also download and add external jar files(mail.jar and activation.jar)
2.how to resolve error?`

This suggests that the javax.mail and javax.activation are not available at runtime, even though you might have added the JAR files to your project. You should ensure that the libs are added correctly in the project's classpath. You can verify by checking those present in the external libraries.
